# Ruby Gems don't include dependencies in $LOAD_PATH

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I try to use `ruby` `gem`s, but as soon I try to use them they complain that they can't load a certain file, e.g.:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/parslet-1.7.1/lib/parslet/context.rb:2:in `require': cannot load such file -- blankslate (LoadError)
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/parslet-1.7.1/lib/parslet/context.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/parslet-1.7.1/lib/parslet/transform.rb:257:in `require'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/parslet-1.7.1/lib/parslet/transform.rb:257:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/parslet-1.7.1/lib/parslet.rb:299:in `require'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/parslet-1.7.1/lib/parslet.rb:299:in `<top (required)>'
```

I looked into the file and the offending line reads:

```
require 'blankslate'
```

I have that library installed. When I try to add the file using the `$:` global variable, the next `require` will throw that error, and so it goes on...

What is causing this?

Comment: Have you installed the gem localy?

Comment: No I don't think so.